# How to change app icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

I'd like to change the icon of a app downloaded from the store. I googled it but just found out how to change basic icons like the desktop, bin, ...

Is it even possible to change windows-foreign icons?

At the image you can see which app I mean (ColorNote)

[image]

Comment: take a look at [Change .exe Icon](https://www.howtogeek.com/75983/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-modify-the-icon-of-an-.exe-file/)

Comment: @yass How do I find the .exe file for windows-store-apps?

Answer (score 2):

Use the tool [TileIconifier](https://github.com/Jonno12345/TileIconifier/releases/latest) to create a custom link with a different icon.

Run the tool, click on "New custom shortcut", select here the tab "Windows Store", here select the app and create the shortcut.

In the main menu, select the shortcut of the app, double click on the `medium icon` entry and select the custom icon from an exe or your own .ico file and press `ok`

[image]

In last step, click on Tile Iconify

[image]

Now on start->all app->TileIconify, you see the new shortcut with the new icon, do a right click on the icon and select `pin to start`.

Now you have the modified icon on start.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how can I change the icon in my taskbar too? Because only on the start menu the icon changes, not in taskbar or the icon next to the files which open with that specific app (exaple: word, powerpoint, excel, ...)

Comment: @Seraphina sorry, I never tried this for taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Install tilelconifier and follow the steps on screen.

You can take the easy route and just search for the application you want to modify in tilelconify's search bar, then click on the application, then double click in the box where it says ''double click me!''.

Now select an icon from the list or if you want to choose a custom one click 'browse'.

Once you've picked an image and clicked ''ok'', you can now also remove the text[ by clicking this marked area:

[image]

change the tile's background colour:

[image]

and adjust the image with the controls marked:

[image]

Now click on 'tile iconify!' and you're done.  it's all pretty self explanatory.